# App tries to load a storyboard the code doesn't try to load

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard

I recently released a major version for an app that used to have a single storyboard called `Main_iPhone`. Part of this release, we splitted the single storyboard in smaller storyboards and removed the main one.

Everything went fine until we released the app and we now receive quite a lot of crash reports saying `Could not find a storyboard named 'Main_iPhone' in bundle NSBundle </var/containers/Bundle/Application/D4A0C73C-F9B6-43D4-A2AD-6055DAF292E9/<APP_NAME>.app> (loaded)`. I repeat this version of the app doesn't have the storyboard `Main_iPhone` anymore but the app seems to try to load it somewhere.

I've honestly looked in every source and configuration files. I've used Xcode's feature to search for a mention of this storyboard and I've run a `grep -R` on every files in the project and I didn't find any mention of this storyboard. I'm now really running out of ideas about what could try to load this file. By any chance, has anyone encounter the same issue before? Has anyone an idea of how I could find where this file is referenced?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: searched in plist file

Comment: Yes I've searched in all the plist files

Answer (score -1):

1. Check Target Membership of your storyboard.
2. Check Main Interface on your target (or you can change the storyboard name and reset Main Interface).
3. Check Copy Bundle Resources on your target.

Comment: 1 and 2 are impossible as the Main storyboard doesn't exist anymore. I've already checked Copy Bundle Resources without any success.